# Upload a github action artifact to LATEST release

Tags: git, github, github-pages, github-api, github-actions

I want to upload a artifact to latest release...
**without creating a new release.**

I started with github official action [upload-release-asset](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/upload-a-release-asset) to upload artifact.
It requires a **upload_url** as an input which tells it the url of release.
Which is generally taken from creating a release in previous step with [create-release](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-a-release) action.

I tried to print output url from create_release-

```
https://uploads.github.com/repos/atiqg/test/releases/28579698/assets{?name,label}
```

Then I changed it to direct to latest release-

```
https://uploads.github.com/repos/atiqg/test/releases/latest/assets
```

Which oblivously did not work out and thrown this error-

```
##[error]Multipart form data required
```

Is there any way I can do this? I don't want to create a new release from actions.
I want to create release normally then action should upload artifact to latest release...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `latest` doesn't work, you can use GitHub API to get `upload_url`...

https://api.github.com/repos/actions/checkout/releases/latest

...and then pass it to `upload-release-asset`.

In workflow it would look something like this

```yaml
- run:   |
         upload_url=$(curl -sL https://api.github.com/repos/actions/checkout/releases/latest | jq -r '.upload_url')
         echo UPLOAD_URL=$upload_url >> $GITHUB_ENV
  shell: bash

- uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
  with:
   upload_url: ${{ env.UPLOAD_URL }}
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore because set-env is deactivated by default, but can easily be fixed by using `echo UPLOAD_URL=$upload_url >> $GITHUB_ENV` instead of `echo ::set-env name=UPLOAD_URL::$upload_url`